# Tomcat 7 in Eclipse Indigo with security enabled shows blank JSP pages

Tags: java, security, jsp, permissions, tomcat7

I am running apache-tomcat-7.0.27 as a server inside Eclipse Indigo SR 2

I have a web application deployed and I am trying to configure JAAS login module. I found that the Login module won't start until the security is enabled in Tomcat. I did this with double clicking the server configuration and setting the security check box there.

My problem is that when this is enabled all JSPs stop showing any content, only a blank page is served. Static pages are not affected. I guess this is some bug in the Eclipse provided catalina.policy Some permission needs to be added there in order for JSPs to work properly. This is my guess at least. I don't see any errors in the tomcat log.

Any suggestions, please?

EDIT: It turned out that this happens only with the login and error pages defined for the FORM  authentication I am using. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Check your tomcat logs, your application may be lacking a [SecurityPermission](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/appA.html#SecurityPermission).